# Localization and enableModifiedFlag

Tags: xpages

When using the enableModifiedFlag you can set a custom message in modifiedMessage. However, in the prompt the rest of the text is in English:

Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? and
Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.

Is there a way to translate this text or have it to follow localization?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot confirm this:
in a localized xpages application I just defined the properties enableModifiedFlag = true and entered some fixed string in "modifiedMessage":

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    modifiedMessage="Wollen Sie wirklich speichern?"
    enableModifiedFlag="true">
```

This automatically genereates the corresponding entries in both property files for localization "xpageName.properties" and "xpageName_en.properties" as follows:

```
/xp\:view[1]/@modifiedMessage=Wollen Sie wirklich speichern?
```

and

```
/xp\:view[1]/@modifiedMessage=[en| Wollen Sie wirklich speichern? ]
```

(as you see my source language is [de] with [en] being the secondary language). The application propreties are set accordingly (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sorry for not being precise in my question, but our problem is related to Notes client (Norwegian version) and not the modified message text itself, but the text that Notes automatic inserts above and below this in the dialog.
We have tried both in localized application and in none-localized version, but Notes always insert the automatic generated text in English.
Do you think there is a way to have this translated?

Comment: since I never really worked with that feature: maybe you could present some screenshot to give me/us an idea of what you mean by "above" and "below"

Comment: Hi again, sorry for not doing this initially.  
  
Below you see the dialog that users get when navigating away from a none-saved document. The text set with the modifiedMessage parameter is in the middle line. The top and bottom line comes automatic, and we have not found a solution to translate these.  
  
![modifiedFlag dialog](http://romsdal.com/modifiedFlag.png)

Comment: That's weird indeed. I just searched the entire workspace directory for that string but no trace of it. It must be hardcoded somewhere which would be really mean

Comment: Ok, thanks a  lot for your help. Hope IBM will improve this in a future release.

Comment: For the interest, IBM have been able to recreate this problem and it is registered as SPR #RGAU8WSF9L. They also confirmed that there are no work-arounds for this problem.

Comment: @LotharMueller Since the top and bottom line are not changeable, I guess you could provide more text that translates those two lines in the middle - it might confuse someone who speaks both English and the local language, but I'd think it would be a good temporary solution.